# when reloading vuejs component 'props' is updating but reference to 'props' via the 'this' scope still referencing previously loaded props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I have a vuejs component which renders out a post and its replies.

When the user wants to view the post, they click on the post title and it opens post in a modal window by calling the component which gets the post data and renders it out.

I have this strange reactivity problem which is a bit difficult to explain.  Best explained with a use case.

1. Click to open Post 1 (all is OK)
2. Close that modal.
3. Click to open Post 2 (strange things happen).

If I reference post in the template (e.g. `{{post.comments}}`, it is displaying all the information for Post 2 just fine

BUT if I reference `this.post.comments` in the script block it is rendering information from Post 1.

So it seems the `post` props itself is updating, but `this.post` seems to reference the first post opened regardless of if I pass a new post in as a props.

If I go further and pass Post 3 into the component.. `post` references Post 3, but `this.post` is still populated with Post 1.

So the props is updating, but this scope is not updating whenever I recall the component with a new props being passed in.

Here is my vuejs code (or top relevant part anyway).

```
module.exports = {
    props: ['post'],
    data: function(){
        return {
            userHasVoted: this.post.userHasVoted,
            votes: this.post.voters.length,
            showReply: false,
            replyPlaceholder: "Post reply here",
            reply: {
                comment_of: this.post._id,
                channel: this.post.channel,
                post: null,
                tags: []
            },
            tagify: null,
            showByIndex: null
        }
    },
       methods: {
.....
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance on unraveling this.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem / solution.

It appears that although I was binding the component to a property in the parent, reloading or changing the parent property does not remount or change the local scope in the component.  So to get around this I needed to use the :key when calling the component.

So this was my original call to the component (passing in a post object)

```
<post-item-full v-bind:post="post"></post-item-full>
```

All I needed to do was add the key, and pass in a unique key (in this case the _id of the object passing in.. but could be anything unique to the post.

```
<post-item-full v-bind:post="post" :key="post._id"></post-item-full>
```

And now working find.

Not sure if this is the right solution, but works without too much fuss.

Thanks to this post for the solution: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/